# How to share a Vpn Internet connection

Tags: networking, vpn

follow my scenario:

1. Router Internet without possibility to configure a VPN
2. Laptop Ubuntu with wifi and ethernet. Configured on it a VPN.
3. Other device where i cannot install a VPN.

I would like to use as gateway Laptop 2 and his VPN tunnel for device 3.

How to configure in Ubuntu a VPN and use it as gateway for others device ?

Thanks